# Bad user-touch recognizing and pressing delays on tableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, touches

I have a problem with recognizing user touches on my `TableView`. When scroll down the page and then try to press an answer (table cell) it's sometimes didn't recognized and I need to press it again and after this - it's working. Sometimes I need to press it 2 or 3 times and only after that button will be pressed.

[not active state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhXvv.png)

[pressed state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3qyC.png)

I notice, that when I press the cell and hold it to 1-1,5 seconds - it's working always, but when I tap it very fast - sometimes it's not.

My TableView is the subview in `ScrollView` and I think that the problem is in `ScrollView`. I tried to set

`self.tableView.delaysContentTouches = NO;`

in

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` method but it's not helped.

If someone knows how I might fix it, please help.

Comment: have you added and tapgesture recognizer ?

Comment: what is the UIButton event?